# Light White water vapour like smoke from exhaust continues throughout the journey

Tags: coolant, smoke, corsa, water-leak

I have a

```
Make:Vauxhall/Opel 
Model:Corsa 
EngineSize: 1.4 
Registered in year: 2012
FuelType = Petrol
```

A day before I noticed a light white smoke from the rear view mirrors and I was already an hour into the journey. I reached home and got my flatmate to rev the engine and I could see light white smoke exactly like water vapour.

I researched online and most people say that it is just condensation and water building up in my exhaust due to cold/wet weather(I am from UK so wet cold almost everyday) and they say the white vapour like smoke should disappear after the engine reaches certain temperature.

But in my case the water vapour like smoke, though very light is always there. Most people suggested a coolant leaking into the engine, and I did mark the coolant level with a black marker before driving and after about an hour or so of driving I reached home and checked the coolant the level seems to be consistent and hasn't fall below the black mark.

Another thing is that my car recently leaks rain water only at the driver's side floor. Could this be as well.

What is going on with my car ??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you. Any suggestions/answer to my question.??

Comment: I’m thinking coolant in the engine. Need to check coolant levels in morning before starting vehicle. Need to check BOTH overflow and radiator if your vehicle has a simple overflow bottle design. My guess is coolant loss will be noticeable when measured that way.  Question:  can you smell the smoke?  It’s not oil, right?

Comment: @zipzit Hi I did check my coolant with a black marker, and so didn't notice anything. While smelling the smoke I, it doesn't smell oil, it just smells like water vapor.

Comment: Smells like chemicalized water vapor

Comment: @SanjokGurung - I'm not sure what type of system your coolant is ... if you have an overflow versus a surge tank, you may not ever see a difference there. I agree, I think your sucking coolant.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you. But the white smoke is extremely light, like the one when we cold start on a winter, My only problem is the extremely light vapour stays throughout the journey.

Comment: Which is indicative of the engine burning coolant.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank  you, I have booked an appointment with the garage next week. Am I to expect a hefty bill ?? The car is supposed to be a very economic car.

Comment: If there is a head gasket leak, it won't be cheap. The labor involved is what will cost the most, as the parts aren't that expensive (usually).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you, would rainwater leak has anything to do with it ??

Comment: Not with a continual stream of white vapor coming from the exhaust. Antifreeze you can see in almost any whether when it's coming out of your tail pipe. Rainwater would act just like regular exhaust. Exhaust has a lot of water in it to start with.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thank you, sorry for all these questions as this is my first car. I did another check yesterday and asked my flat mate to rev the engine for me and I held my palm right in front of the exhaust and when he revved a engine quite hard, a small puff of white steam, it was literally steam and my palm was wet from it. I felt around the exhaust tip and it was very wet, drips of liquid coming out. To correct the white steam seems to come out only when revved high. I still feel like its just water vapour though.